# Button remains visible when disabled

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have created a custom button in IB which performs a play video function for me. But sometimes when the video is not available I want to have the button disabled & invisible.

the button is linked to the code by having dragged the IBOutlet.

so when I do `[playButton setEnabled:NO]` it gets disabled, but it's still visible, although becomes transparent. I need it completely disappeared. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `playButton.hidden = YES` to hide it.
Disabling only prevents user interaction

Comment: Glad to be of help ! Don't forget to accept the answer to close the question